# Measurable function which is not equivalent to real continuous function

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Hi Can anyone help with the following problem:

1. Does there exist a measurable function $f:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$ which is not equivalent to any real continuous function on $[0,1]$?
2. Does there exist a non-measurable function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $f^{-1}(y)$ is measurable for any $y\in\mathbb{R}$.

Intuitively I believe that both of the answers are 'Yes, but I don't know how to prove?

Can anyone help. It would be highly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by equivalent in 1? Different on a set of positive measure or what?

Answer (score 1):

The first one is pretty simple, the indicator function $\mathbf 1_{[0;1]}$ is not equivalent to any continuous function.

The second question is a bit more complicated, take $f:x\to x+\mathbf 1_{V}$ where $V$ is a non measurable subset of $[0;1]$. This function is not measurable (or else $f(x)-x=\mathbf 1_{V}$ would also be measurable) but $f^{-1}(y)$ has at most $2$ elements for every $y$, so it is measurable.

Comment: What do you mean by $\mathbf{1}_{[0;1]}$? Is it an indicator function?

Comment: Hi Could you explain why $f^{-1}(y)$ will be measurable

Comment: Yes it's an indicator function. And as I said $f^{-1}(y)$ is a set with at most $2$ elements, any set of the form $\{a;b\}$ with $a$ and $b$ real is trivially measurable (with $0$ measure).